# How to extract part of string in Visual Basic Scripting (VBS)?

Tags: string, batch-file, math, vbscript

I am working on a school project for "TechnoExpo". I need to know how to pull the string in between two "()"'s, and I need to know how to calculate four variables.

```
Input One Example: 6(3)
Input Two Example: 2(7)
```

I need to set "6" to a variable named "X1", "3" to a variable named "Y1", "2" to a variable named "X2", and finaly "7" to a variable named "Y2". Next I need to calculate ("Y2"-"Y1") divided by ("X2"-"X2"). From here I can display the information on my own. Here is a beta batch file version.

```
@Echo Off
:StartUpConfiguration
Cls
Mode Con Cols=50 Lines=25
Color 0F

:Start
Set /P CordinateOne=[One]
Set /P CordinateTwo=[Two]
For /F "Tokens=1,2 delims=()" %%A In ("%CordinateOne%") Do Set "X1=%%A" & set "Y1=%%B"
For /F "Tokens=1,2 delims=()" %%A In ("%CordinateTwo%") Do Set "X2=%%A" & set "Y2=%%B"
Echo Slope:
Set /A Y=%Y2%-%Y1%
Set /A X=%X2%-%X1%
Set /A M=%Y%/%X%
Echo [%M%]
Echo.
Echo %Y2% - %Y1% [%Y%]
Echo %X2% - %X1% [%X%]
Pause
```

Comment: and what is the problem??

Comment: you want this in vbs?

Comment: I would like this in vbs, not vb. The problem is I don't know how to do math with variables and I don't know how to pull the different strings from the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
strInput1 = UserInput( "CordinateOne=:" )
strInput2 = UserInput( "CordinateTwo=:" )


substr1=Split(strInput1,"(")
substr2=Split(strInput2,"(")

X1=CInt(substr1(0))
Y1=CInt(Split(substr1(1),")")(0))

X2=CInt(substr2(0))
Y2=CInt(Split(substr2(1),")")(0))

X=X2-X1
Y=Y2-Y1
M=Y/X
MI=Y Mod X

Wscript.Echo "[" & M & "]" & "or [" & M & "." & MI & "]"
Wscript.Echo ""
Wscript.Echo Y2 & "-" & Y1 & " [" & Y & "]"
Wscript.Echo X2 & "-" & X1 & " [" & X & "]"  


Function UserInput( myPrompt )
' This function prompts the user for some input.
' When the script runs in CSCRIPT.EXE, StdIn is used,
' otherwise the VBScript InputBox( ) function is used.
' myPrompt is the the text used to prompt the user for input.
' The function returns the input typed either on StdIn or in InputBox( ).
' Written by Rob van der Woude
' http://www.robvanderwoude.com
    ' Check if the script runs in CSCRIPT.EXE
    If UCase( Right( WScript.FullName, 12 ) ) = "\CSCRIPT.EXE" Then
        ' If so, use StdIn and StdOut
        WScript.StdOut.Write myPrompt & " "
        UserInput = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine
    Else
        ' If not, use InputBox( )
        UserInput = InputBox( myPrompt )
    End If
End Function
```

You can execute this both with `cscript.exe` and `wscript.exe`  .No validation for the input.

Answer (score 1):

Answering to your title `How to extract part of string in Visual Basic Scripting (VBS)?` :

Here is all the info that you'll need:

[MSDN: Mid Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wffts6k3%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[W3Schools: Mid Function](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_mid.asp)

Example:

```
txt="This is a beautiful day!"
wscript.Echo(Mid(txt,1,1))
```

Comment: The two numbers are coordinates, I still don't know how to set each number as a coordinate.